# SP is Undefined in SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I got "Type is undefined" and "SP is undefined" message when I try to open the list form in sharepoint modal dialog. Could anyone help me to resolve this issue?

This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/_layouts/SPP.ContentDesigner/Scripts/SP.UI.Dialog.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript">


     //Handle the DialogCallback callback 
          function DialogCallback(dialogResult, returnValue){ 
          } 

 //Open the Dialog 
          function OpenEditDialog(id) {
              debugger;
       var options = { 
         url:"http://devcd/Lists/NewTest/EditForm.aspx?ID=1&IsDlg=1", 
         width: 700, 
         height: 700, 
         dialogReturnValueCallback: DialogCallback 
         }; 
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options); 
      }
      </script>
```

Comment: In which context this js code run? web part page, or application page, or other?

Comment: refer answer from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272753/sharepoint-2010-modal-dialog-doesnt-work-properly), it may be helpful.

Comment: i got this error in sharepoint application page, my actual requirement is it should work on all type of pages(webpart page, application page, publishing page). could you guide me please?

Comment: Hm, it works on application page for me, why do you include this script - src="/_layouts/SPP.ContentDesigner/Scripts/SP.UI.Dialog.js"? Try to rename it, may be some conflicts with standard file occure.

Comment: if i comment this line itself i got the same issue, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 10):

SP.js uses "lazy load". Invoke your function inside ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(OpenEditDialog, "SP.js")
```

Answer (score 8):

I suggest get rid of the first script reference...

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/_layouts/SPP.ContentDesigner/Scripts/SP.UI.Dialog.js"></script>
```

...and load the scripts by page or master page server controls.
Then control the error situation in your component code like http://microsoft-techies.blogspot.com/2014/05/script5007-unable-to-get-property.html.

Code sample:

```
try {
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
catch (error) {
    SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
}
```

Comment: this approach is more promising.

Answer (score 2):

I  battled with this for a good while - in my case changing "LoadAfterUI" attribute in the ScriptLink to "true" fixed it where nothing else worked.

Comment: As you can see in the question, the scripts are not loaded with the ScriptLink control, so this does not really apply

Answer (score -2):

You can fix this issue by using a generic object for option instead of the DialogOptions class. that mean you have to write option like this:

```
//Using a generic object.
var options = {
    title: "My Dialog Title",
    width: 400,
    height: 600,
    url: "/_layouts/DialogPage.aspx" };
```

for more information about using it, visit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410058%28v=office.14%29.aspx and see the example.

Comment: The code above is already using a generic object... The issue is that the code after (SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog) is executed before SP.js is loaded