# How do get selected item of list?

Tags: web-part, javascript, client-object-model

I have a webpart .I add a listviewbyquary in createchildcontrols and a hyperlink in visualwebpart.

i use this

http://graegert.com/featured/using-the-editorpart-to-create-a-custom-listview-web-part

I want get selected item in ListView when hyperlink click.
i use this code in webpart

```
<script >
function geturl()
{
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.web = context.get_web();
var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
var list = this.web.get_lists().getById(listId);
var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);  //Get selected   documents
var itemId = items[0];
var url="@Url"+itemId;
return url;
 </script>
```

and code in Hyperlink

```
<a href="javascript:geturl()" >click</a>
```

but don't work .

var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); is null

**//Edit**

This code return the value when i use in list page , but when i use on Webpart , don't work

Comment: I've checked this code - it's work fine. Are you sure your js code executed? Can you give full code of linkbutton?

Comment: yes , Please read my update.

Comment: Have you tried OnClientClick rather than PostBackURL? And when calling your function, you should need brackets. And a 'runat="server" ' attribute.

Comment: Yes , i have tried. but doesn't work.

Comment: Is it a standard XsltListViewWebPart?

Comment: Yes , i use http://graegert.com/featured/using-the-editorpart-to-create-a-custom-listview-web-part

Comment: Why dont use SP jquery  library :)

Comment: I was facing the same issue, i tried with var context=this.SP.ClientContext.get_current();

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't run postback (by defining postbackurl in your linkbutton). If postback occurs, javascript looses its context.

Just add simple html markup such as:

```
<a href="javascript:getSelectedItemUrl()">Click on me </a>
```

To get the id of the first selected list item:

```
SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems()[0].id
```

If SP.ClientContext.get_current() is null, [then you have to ensure SP.js is loaded first, like in this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/26224/2580):

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetUrl, "SP.js")
```

So your code can be encapsulated in this ExecuteOrDelay..:

```
function getSelectedItemUrl() {
  ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetUrl, "SP.js");
}
function GetUrl() {
  return @url + SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems()[0].id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , but when i use this code,i come across this error:The value of the property 'ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded' is null or undefied , not a function object

Comment: What masterpage do you use. Is ScriptManager included?

Comment: Yes , i use v4.master.

Comment: Weird. Can you try someghing in Browser Console (F12) when your sharepoint page is loaded, like SP.ListOperation

Comment: yes, when i load page , i found SP.ListOperation

Comment: Well, if you can do it manually, but it doesn't work in your linkbutton, then something is wrong with event order or, like I said with postbackurl. Try the same code with <a href="javascript:someFunc();">hhh</a> or <input onclick="someFunc();"...

Comment: I use <a href="javascript:someFunc();">hhh</a> , but don't work :(

Comment: Well, then I can't help without seing more code. I hope you can figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the script is for it is included? I had problem before that the correct script files not where included.