# selected SPListItem in the current list

Tags: splistitem, splist, multi-select

how to get the selected SPListItems in the current SPList ?
I thought I would find a helping property like this:

```
SPListItemCollection mySelectedItems = SPContext.Current.List.getSelectedSPListItems();
```

but this wasn't available, so any idea how to retrieve these items ?

Answer (score 1):

Glolita,

I don't know about getting selected items at server-side, however personally I get the selected items in Javascript like this:

```
 var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
 var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
 var myItems = '';
 var i;

 for (i in items)
 {
     myItems += '|' + items[i].id;
 }
```

and assign this value to a Hidden Field in Javascript as:

```
 document.getElementById("<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>").value = myItems;
```

and then call server-side code by clicking a hidden button pro grammatically:

```
 document.getElementById("buttonId").click();
```

OR Send this as Query String to the page which contains Visual Web Part and access the Query String at Server-side...

[a similar question here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26935/how-do-get-selected-item-of-list)

Please have a look at [this post](http://tomaszrabinski.pl/wordpress/2012/02/25/get-selected-list-items-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: Great answer, thanks ! one more question please : what is exactely the type of the variable items? is it: string array ? object collection? because I want to retrieve from those items their attached files on the server side

Comment: Glolita, in javascript you don't need to worry about the type... when you have all the item Id's concatenated with '|' in a HiddenField, you can then Split the ids and loop through the ids and get specific items!